# $\sum\limits_i a_i^2\sum\limits_i b_i^2+\left(\sum\limits_ia_i b_i\right)^2\geq \sqrt{\sum\limits_i a_i^4\sum\limits_i b_i^4}+\sum\limits_ia_i^2b_i^2$

Tags: inequality, conjectures

I have no idea about how to prove (or disprove) the following inequality:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i b_i\right)^2\geq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^4\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^4\right)}+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2b_i^2,\quad a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}, \ n>1.
$$
I ran some numerical simulations and no counterexample showed up yet.

**Note 1.** The inequality holds true for $n=2$, as shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a_1%5E2%2Ba_2%5E2)(b_1%5E2%2Bb_2%5E2)%2B(a_1*b_1%2Ba_2*b_2)%5E2-(a_1%5E2*b_1%5E2%2Ba_2%5E2*b_2%5E2))%5E2-(a_1%5E4%2Ba_2%5E4)(b_1%5E4%2Bb_2%5E4)).

**Note 2.** This conjecture was formulated by Fedor Petrov in an attempt to provide a solution to a particular case of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233546/a-log-inequality-for-positive-definite-trace-one-matrices).

---

**EDIT.** The inequality has been finally proved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259637/a-seemingly-simple-inequality).

Comment: What happens if you square both sides and try to match up terms?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I tried but it didn't help me. Also, I think that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can help at some point, but I'm still stuck at the moment...

Comment: $a_i$, $b_i$ should be non-negative.

Comment: Where does it inequality come from? When $a_i,b_i$ have the same sign for any $i$, it's clearly true, but otherwise it's not easy.

Comment: It may turn out as a crazy idea, but have you tried to prove the inequality by induction on $n$?

Comment: The Left Hand Side of the inequality gives me a feeling for C-S...

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes almost entirely from Markus Sprecher on MathOverflow found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259675/114053).

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left(\sum_{i>j} (a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_i)^2 \right)^2\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a^4_i\right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^n b^4_i\right).
$$
The left hand side is greater than or equal to
$$
\sum_i a_i^4b_i^4+\sum_{i>j} (a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^4+2(a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^2\big((a_ib_i)^2+(a_jb_j)^2)+2(a_ib_i)^2\cdot(a_jb_j)^2
$$
Since
$$
(a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^4+2(a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^2\big((a_ib_i)^2+(a_jb_j)^2\big)+2(a_ib_i)^2\cdot(a_jb_j)^2\geq a_i^4b_j^4+a_j^4b_i^4.
$$
is equivalent to
$$
(a_ib_j+a_jb_i)^2(a_ib_i+a_jb_j)^2\geq 0,
$$
the LHS is greater than or equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^4b_i^4+\sum_{i>j} a_i^4b_j^4+a_j^4b_i^4=\sum_{i=1}^n a^4_i \sum_{i=1}^n b^4_i.
$$

Comment: I added the answer (with minor revisions) to clear this question from the unanswered queue following the suggestion of Henning found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3139/43239). If it should be marked as CW, please mark it as such.